# EaselJS shape x,y properties confusion

Tags: easeljs

I generate a 4x4 grid of squares with below code.  They all draw in correct position, rows and columns, on canvas on stage.update().  But the x,y coordinates for all sixteen of them on inspection are 0,0.  Why?  Does each shape has it's own x,y coordinate system?  If so, if I get a handle to a shape, how do I determine where it was drawn originally onto the canvas?

The EaselJS documentation is silent on the topic ;-).  Maybe you had to know Flash.

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var square = new createjs.Shape();                                            
            square.graphics.drawRect(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
            console.log("Created square + square.x + "," + square.y);
            stage.addChild(square);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing the graphics at the coordinates you want, instead of drawing them at 0,0, and moving them using x/y coordinates. If you don't set the x/y yourself, it will be 0. EaselJS does not infer the x/y or width/height based on the graphics content ([more info](http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/)).

Here is an updated fiddle where the graphics are all drawn at [0,0], and then positioned using x/y instead: http://jsfiddle.net/0o63ty96/

Relevant code:

```
square.graphics.beginStroke("red").drawRect(0,0,100,100);
square.x = i * 100;
square.y = j * 100;
```

Comment: Thank you!  After I typed this question, I suspected this might be the answer - that my assumption that the draw rectangle call would somehow set the x/y for the square instance was incorrect.  It seems like a little confusing API - nut fully object oriented (i.e.  new Rectangle(x, y, width, height) - but now that I understand what it's doing should be no problem.